# the ending character in timestamp string

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

The timestamp string is something like :

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Timestamp(2020, 3, 14, 15)
Timestamp('2020-03-14 15:00:00')
```

Or you can insert some character between date and time.

```
import datetime
dateTime = datetime.datetime.today()
print(dateTime.isoformat(sep="T"))
2023-05-20T08:53:09.815989
```

I have found that someone add an ending character `Z` in timestamp string:

```
2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

List all timezone:

```
import pytz
for timeZone in pytz.all_timezones_set:
    print(timeZone)
```

No a single `Z` in the output.
Is it a standard way to add an ending character in timestamp string?

Comment: If your time is not UTC time, don't add the Z; you'll be lying.  If it is, just append it: `print(dateTime.isoformat(sep="T")+'Z')`

Comment: Does `Z` means UTC time?

Comment: Z means UTC time. It used to be called Zulu time, before it became Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), which becaume UTC.

Comment: Yes, `Z` is a standard designation for the UTC time zone.  I believe it's the only time zone with a single character abbreviation.

Comment: @KenWhite it's called Zulu because that's the military way of unambiguously saying "Z".

Comment: @MarkRansom: I'm aware. Ex-military myself. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite didn't mean to imply you were ignorant of the origin, sorry if that's how it came across.  Just wanted to inform those who came across your comment and weren't aware.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No offense taken. You must have missed my :-) at the end of my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Ken White's concept `Zulu time`,i have searched on the website to get more info,it use `Military Phonetic Alphabet` to denote all the timezones,`Z` means  UTC time.

https://veteran.com/military-time/